# Java: Does anyone have method to find best match of string in array?

Tags: java, pattern-matching, matching, string-matching

Basically I'm just trying to find a way to find the closest match (not necessarily exact) of a `String`

For example, find `"delicous"` in `{"pie", "delicious", "test"}`

This is pretty obvious, but the values in the array might not always be that distinct.

Could someone please help me with a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Depends on how you define "closest" but one common way is by using a [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) score. Apache Commons has such [a method in StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#getLevenshteinDistance(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)).

From there your search method basically becomes: find the string in the collection which has the smallest Levenshtein distance for a given input.

Comment: Thanks, this is working pretty well :) If I have chocolatedessert and chocolatepie and I type chocolatedes it seems to go for pie still, but it's still much better than before :p Thanks a ton!

Comment: Second link is broken. Please update. (this is possibly the link - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#getLevenshteinDistance(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence) )

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing built into Java for that. You might try a third-party library like [SecondString](http://secondstring.sourceforge.net/) or [FREJ](http://frej.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

Another approach that can be used in conjunction with Levenshtein Distance is taking the phonetic representation of the words first.  One algorithm to do this is [Metaphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone).

The [user guide for Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/userguide.html) has details of this and some other encoders.